# Multiple IF statement including formulas as True response

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

0

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1siXWH_83AFnymr58f72xBmwFlPG1O5ZHZgA1JqQNt0w/edit?usp=sharing Above is test document. I am trying to import information from sheet "AM Trip" to Sheet "BL AM", I only need some columns and only depending on if column T,U, or V has a 1 in it and that seems to be working. My problem is I wish the dropdown list in Cell B2 to change the information being imported which is starting from cell B6. I used below formula in Cell B6, but I have a parse error and not sure how to fix it.

```
=IFS(B2="That", "=QUERY('AM trip'!B7:W42,"SELECT C, E, G, L, O, P, Q, R, S, W WHERE (U is not null)", false)", B2="This", "=QUERY('AM trip'!B7:W42,"SELECT C, E, G, L, O, P, Q, R, S, W WHERE (V is not null)", false)", B2="Other", "=QUERY('AM trip'!B7:W42,"SELECT C, E, G, L, O, P, Q, R, S, W WHERE (T is not null)", false)")
```

When I look into the cell the section from "Select" to "is not null)" it is black and I am sure that is the issue but not sure how to fix it. Thanks for any help. Paul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new at this, but I think I found a couple of minor problems in your sheet.

First, your data validation list for, B2, does not require quotes.  And I changed your list of values for B2 from "This","That","Other" to Soca,Salsa,Calypso.
The main issue was that your formula in B6 had quotes around the Query functions.
Lastly, I don't believe that IFS and QUERY work reliably together, so changed it to a multiple IF formula.

So I changed this:

```
=IFS(B2="Salsa",   "=QUERY('AM trip'!B7:W42,"SELECT C, E, G, L, O, P, Q, R, S, W 
                                             WHERE (U is not null)", false)", 
     B2="Soca",    "=QUERY('AM trip'!B7:W42,"SELECT C, E, G, L, O, P, Q, R, S, W 
                                             WHERE (V is not null)", false)",
     B2="Calypso", "=QUERY('AM trip'!B7:W42,"SELECT C, E, G, L, O, P, Q, R, S, W 
                                             WHERE (T is not null)", false)")
```

to this:

```
=IF(    B2="Soca",    QUERY('AM trip'!B7:W42,"SELECT C, E, G, L, O, P, Q, R, S, W 
                                              WHERE (U is not null)", false),
   IF(  B2="Salsa",   QUERY('AM trip'!B7:W42,"SELECT C, E, G, L, O, P, Q, R, S, W 
                                              WHERE (V is not null)", false), 
     IF(B2="Calypso", QUERY('AM trip'!B7:W42,"SELECT C, E, G, L, O, P, Q, R, S, W 
                                              WHERE (T is not null)", false), "Blank")))
```

Here is a working example - your sheet was locked for editing, so I made a copy.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HgyZURww4K_UTynxKCwZq6MxLh-58j3fccSC0fvxBa0/edit?usp=sharing

Let me know if you still have issues after seeing this.

Comment: Thanks, now it works, only issue I see is i would like to to start the query in "B7" So i can have a header in "B6".  So it takes information from B7 on AMTrip and pastes from B7 in BLAM.  I tried adding ={"time"; IF.... to the box of B6 to have a heading in the box, however if got this error :- "In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows." even though I added the second curly bracket } after the final ) of 3rd query.  Any more ideas??  Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Also is there any way I can change the N/A# error to No data or somesuch, if there is no matching data?

Comment: Paul, I'm not positive that I understood what you wanted, but I moved the formula to B7, so you can type in your headings in B6 to O6, the row above.  I also added error detenction, so "No Data" if no results found.

Comment: And your formula in A6, to calculate the number seems very complicated to me, but it does do the job.   If you want to replace it with a simpler formula, you might prefer something like this in A7. ............................                                             = arrayformula( if( C7:C <> "", ROW(A7:A)-6 ,"")

Comment: I think I got the formula where you want it, so it works like your formula in A6, with the header.  I really think it would be easier to do your headings, in A6 to J6, manualyy, ie. typed in, rather than in the formula, but you may have your reasons for that.  Let me know if you want me to move it down to B7, and without the headers.   Or, if you want to type the headers into E6 to M6 of the AM TRIP sheet, then we could pull the headers from there, so they would always be in sync with the data...  does that make sense?

Comment: Perfect, all seems good now, I will run through changes once I am home and have the time to double check everything on the laptop but for now it seems to be everything I wanted, thanks.  Also thanks for the change to A6, when I was making the sheet 8+ years ago that was the only way i could find to get it to do it but will look into changing that now as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212737/discussion-between-paul-and-kirkg13).